# lua's loadstring() not working with tables

Tags: lua

I have some text and I'm trying to load it via load string. The following works:

```
local m = loadstring("data = 5")()
```

But when the data is a table it doesn't work and gives the error "attempt to call a nil"

```
local m = loadstring("data = { 1 = 10}")()
```

Comment: You should verify that the code you're trying to compile is valid Lua code before trying to execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table declaration in lua require integer keys to be put inside square brackets:

```
data = {
  [1] = value,
}
```

The enclosing of keys in square brackets is always allowed, valid and possible. It can be skipped iff your key follows the pattern: `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*` (which is the same as a valid variable name in lua)

Comment: Looks like I need to change my table to sting function!

Answer (score -1):

If you had added an `assert` you would have got a more helpful message:

```
local m = assert (loadstring("data = { 1 = 10}"))()
```

Result:

```
stdin:1: [string "data = { 1 = 10}"]:1: '}' expected near '='
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

---

And to actually answer the question, unless the table key happens to follow Lua variable naming rules, you have to put it inside square brackets, eg.

```
local m = assert (loadstring("data = { [1] = 10}"))()
```

---

> m is still nil when I do this

What does that matter? The `loadstring` is done.

Just do this:

```
assert (loadstring("data = { 1 = 10}"))()
print (data [1])
```

You don't need the variable `m`. The `loadstring` puts a table into `data` - that is the important thing.

Comment: m is still nil when I do this.