# nil value after loadstring on a table

Tags: lua

I'm doing a loadstring() on a table but the result is still a nil value for my variable `m`.

I guess I would expect it to be a table. What am I missing with `loadstring()`? Does it not work this way?

```
local m = assert (loadstring("data = { [1] = 10}"))()
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305846/luas-loadstring-not-working-with-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code inside loadstring should probably be "return {10}".

After running that code, *m* will be nil, but you'll have a global *data*.

Comment: ah I see. Didn't need to say "return" just check the global variable data. My bad. I thought m would be the data. Ty!

Comment: No problem. Replacing "data =" with "return " would put the data inside _m_. You might also check out JSON. Also, if your question is solved, don't forget to set this question as the solution.